# Unity3D Android Game Development

Tags: c#, android, build, unity-game-engine, apk

I am starting to **Export** the game development using unity 3d for android. I am using the unity 4.2.2 version.

In the normal apps which we develop using eclipse, we can deploy onto mobile by copying the apk file. What about unity 3d 4.2.2 version? How do I get apk file using this version with selected Google android project. I don't want to publish on market.with out selecting Google android project i.e easy for getting apk,problem is to select Google android project,so in this way how to get apk please help me.

Answer (score 0):

From the Unity3D editor select File-->Build Setting

Then from the pop windows select Android and press swtich platform if you didnt already switched it. Then Uncheck Google Android Project and press 'build' unity will prompt where you want top save your apk. Selected you desired folder and press save.

Comment: noooo,i have an important of selecting Google Android Project so in This way How to Get APK.@Sheheryar Aamir.

Comment: Then generate apk from eclipse. Import you project in to eclipse then compile it and build apk

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to download and install the Android SDK from Google. I've had a number of problems getting it to 'play nice' with Unity3D in the past, so if the latest version of SDK gives you trouble, consider getting SDK Manager r21, SDK Tools r21 and don't forget to use the Manager to download a valid platform.

Inside Unity3D you need to point to the SDK directory (this is part of the build if you don't have it setup already). Edit->Preferences->External Tools->Android SDK Location and point to the \sdk folder.

From File->Build settings you change the platform to Android (you should be working with this setting anyway). A successful build will produce an APK file.

Building for the Google Play store involves a few extra steps, but this is adequately documented.

Comment: I Did As You told but I am not Get an APK file so wt i can do please help me i am new of unity3d.@Happy Apple

Comment: If you didn't get a successful build it's almost certainly because an error occurred. Consider posting the error message.